# How is the health of my SSD and HDD (why so many read errors?)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

They are from my new laptop.  Why so many read errors from HDD? Is there something wrong with my drive? 
Report from crystaldiskinfo:

---

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskInfo 8.1.0 (C) 2008-2019 hiyohiyo
                                Crystal Dew World : https://crystalmark.info/
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    OS : Windows 10 Professional [10.0 Build 17134] (x64)
  Date : 2019/04/29 20:33:18

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------
 + Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [ATA]
   - ST2000LM015-2E8174
 - Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller [SCSI]
 + Standard NVM Express Controller [SCSI]
   - WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-512G

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-512G : 512.1 GB [0/0/0, sq] - nv
 (2) ST2000LM015-2E8174 : 2000.3 GB [1/1/4, pd1] - st

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-512G
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-512G
        Firmware : 10123000
   Serial Number : 1837C3800778
       Disk Size : 512.1 GB
     Buffer Size : Unknown
    # of Sectors : 
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : NVM Express
   Major Version : NVM Express 1.3
   Minor Version : 
   Transfer Mode : PCIe 3.0 x4 | PCIe 3.0 x4
  Power On Hours : 33 hours
  Power On Count : 81 count
      Host Reads : 1772 GB
     Host Writes : 603 GB
     Temperature : 39 C (102 F)
   Health Status : Good (100 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T.
       APM Level : ----
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 000000000000 Critical Warning
02 000000000138 Composite Temperature
03 000000000064 Available Spare
04 00000000000A Available Spare Threshold
05 000000000000 Percentage Used
06 0000003762C7 Data Units Read
07 00000012DA3C Data Units Written
08 0000011933F7 Host Read Commands
09 0000006E633D Host Write Commands
0A 000000000018 Controller Busy Time
0B 000000000051 Power Cycles
0C 000000000021 Power On Hours
0D 000000000014 Unsafe Shutdowns
0E 000000000000 Media and Data Integrity Errors
0F 000000000000 Number of Error Information Log Entries

-- SMART_NVME --------------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 00 38 01 64 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
020: E8 62 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 40 DA 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
040: 4B 36 19 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
050: 65 63 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
070: 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
080: 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (2) ST2000LM015-2E8174
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : ST2000LM015-2E8174
        Firmware : SDM1
   Serial Number : ZDZ4LADA
       Disk Size : 2000.3 GB (8.4/137.4/2000.3/----)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 3907029168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ACS-3
   Minor Version : ACS-3 Revision 3b
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 31 hours
  Power On Count : 73 count
     Temperature : 26 C (78 F)
   Health Status : Good
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 8080h [ON]
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : D:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 _84 _74 __6 00000D7F2B19 Read Error Rate
03 _99 _99 __0 000000000000 Spin-Up Time
04 100 100 _20 000000000059 Start/Stop Count
05 100 100 _36 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 100 253 _45 00000003A99B Seek Error Rate
09 100 100 __0 61930000001F Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 _97 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0C 100 100 _20 000000000049 Power Cycle Count
B8 100 100 _99 000000000000 End-to-End Error
BB 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reported Uncorrectable Errors
BC 100 100 __0 000000000000 Command Timeout
BD 100 100 __0 000000000000 High Fly Writes
BE _74 _51 _40 00001A15001A Airflow Temperature
BF 100 100 __0 000000000000 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 100 100 __0 00000000000F Power-off Retract Count
C1 100 100 __0 00000000014D Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 _26 _49 __0 00140000001A Temperature
C5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
F0 100 253 __0 C5DD0000000E Head Flying Hours
F1 100 253 __0 0000055CCCFD Total Host Writes
F2 100 253 __0 000025D415EE Total Host Reads
FE 100 100 __0 000000000000 Free Fall Protection

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 0A 00 01 0F 00 54 4A 19 2B 7F 0D 00 00 00 03 03
010: 00 63 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 32 00 64 64 59
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 33 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 07 0F 00 64 FD 9B A9 03 00 00 00 00 09 32
040: 00 64 64 1F 00 00 00 93 61 26 0A 13 00 64 64 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32 00 64 64 49 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 B8 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 32
070: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BC 32 00 64 64 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 BD 3A 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BE 22 00 4A 33 1A 00 15 1A 00 00 00 BF 32
0A0: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 32 00 64 64 0F
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C1 32 00 64 64 4D 01 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C2 22 00 1A 31 1A 00 00 00 14 00 00 C5 12
0D0: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 10 00 64 64 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 3E 00 C8 C8 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 F0 00 00 64 FD 0E 00 00 00 DD C5 2A F1 00
100: 00 64 FD FD CC 5C 05 00 00 00 F2 00 00 64 FD EE
110: 15 D4 25 00 00 00 FE 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 71
170: 03 00 01 00 01 FF 02 46 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 02 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
190: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B3 10 F5 98 1A 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 FD CC 5C 05 00 00 00 00
1C0: EE 15 D4 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 02 00 00 01 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 18 00 00 00 AA

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 01 00 01 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 14 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 07 2D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 61 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 B8 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 00
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BC 00 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 BD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BE 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BF 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F1 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F2 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 92
```

Comment: Both drives show their health as good. Where do you see these errors?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator In hdd section `01 _84 _74 __6 00000D7F2B19 Read Error Rate`

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I do not have data sheets. Just saw the numbers and thought that something may be wrong. Thank you very much for your answer! If you want post answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator also can you recommend any good free bad sector checking program?

Comment: Always use the software from the manufacturer. Seagate offers SeaTools for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High numbers are good for the Read Error Rate value, meaning your drive is quite healthy.

Notice how the Current value is greater than both the Worst and Threshold values. This means when it last got to the recorded Worst value, it had to *decrease* to do so. Therefore, smaller is worse.

SMART values are only of concern when they approach or surpass the Threshold value.

Comment: Here on screenshot, it shows that it is above threshold: https://i.imgur.com/Bl5SBAR.jpg  Is it OK anyway?

Comment: Yes it's OK. It hasn't exceeded the threshold. The value started at 100, so it still has a long way to go until it reaches 6.